# HPGrowingTextView and UIBubbleTableView in one view?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How i can put booth together? If i have the Tableview i need another Delegate for the GrowingTextView. Seems to be very complicated or i am wrong? It is possible to use HPGrowingTextView and UIBubbleTableView in one view? Any hint are very welcome!

Regards,
MOVT

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question in right way... Sure you can, `UIBubbleTableView` requires `UIBubbleTableViewDataSource` while `HPGrowingTextView` requires its own delegate, but still you can implement them in one view controller like this:

```
bubbleTable.bubbleDataSource = self;
growingTextView.delegate = self;
```

Once `HPGrowingTextView` changes its size, `growingTextView:didChangeHeight:` is called (so make sure you have implemented this function in the view controller). All you need to do is to adjust `UIBubbleTableView` based on `HPGrowingTextView` new size. I think this can be even made with auto layout in xib.

Hope this helps to start.